# Cassandra 1.1.2 failure to create secondary index

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I am using Cassandra 1.1.2, the latest, and I am unable to create or recreate secondary indexes. It times out or just does not create, sending out an unknown error message.

By the way I have tried with Cassandra Cluster Admin and the cassandra CLI.
Cassandra CLI spits back "unreachable nodes" whereas Cassandra Cluster Admin shows a blank error message.

Comment: Please provide information about how you're trying to do this. A paste of your cassandra-cli session and any errors you see (or get in the cassandra logs) would help.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have found out that it is due to a mismatched schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out using some Website, the Cassandra FAQ and a forum, I discovered that there was a schema mismatch, and I followed the instructions to attempt to rectify the schema.

It was successful, but I do not know how did the schema get mismatched all by itself.

Here is the link in case anyone is facing the same issue: http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/FAQ#schema_disagreement

Comment: Maybe explaining what you did would be useful for the rest of us, instead of just ragequitting.